# Accent token request is giving error

Tags: vimeo-api

Hi I getting the following response when i request access token from my server using API https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/access_token. Is there some change in this API.
Need help, As this is server, why this response is comming.

---

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
        <title>Vimeo / 429 Too Many Requests</title>

        <script src="//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=en"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var done = function() {
                        document.getElementById('form').submit();
            };
    </script>


        <style type="text/css">
                body {
                        background: #141531;
                        font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
                        font-size: 18px;
                        font-weight: normal;
                        color: #fff;
                }
                p {
                        margin: 0 0 25px 0;
                }
                svg {
                        margin: 75px;
                        width: 250px;
                }
                div.content {
                        margin: 75px;
                        position: absolute;
                        bottom: 0px;
                }
                div.g-recaptcha {
                        width: 304px;
                        height: 78px;
                }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 140 40"><path fill="#fff" d="M31.277 18.832c-.14 3.052-2.27 7.23-6.39 12.53-4.26 5.537-7.863 8.307-10.81 8.307-1.826 0-3.372-1.69-4.634-5.06-.843-3.1-1.686-6.19-2.53-9.28-.937-3.37-1.942-5.06-3.018-5.06-.234 0-1.054.49-2.458 1.473l-1.474-1.9c1.546-1.36 3.07-2.718 4.572-4.08 2.062-1.78 3.61-2.72 4.642-2.813 2.438-.234 3.938 1.433 4.502 5 .6 3.85 1.03 6.247 1.26 7.183.7 3.194 1.472 4.79 2.32 4.79.66 0 1.64-1.037 2.95-3.108 1.31-2.073 2.015-3.65 2.11-4.733.187-1.79-.517-2.684-2.11-2.684-.75 0-1.522.173-2.32.514 1.54-5.044 4.48-7.495 8.825-7.355 3.22.094 4.737 2.183 4.552 6.265z"/><path fill="#fff" d="M50.613 28.713c-1.313 2.484-3.12 4.733-5.417 6.748-3.143 2.72-6.285 4.08-9.425 4.08-1.45 0-2.57-.47-3.34-1.4-.77-.937-1.13-2.152-1.09-3.652.05-1.547.53-3.937 1.44-7.172.92-3.23 1.38-4.966 1.38-5.2 0-1.22-.422-1.83-1.265-1.83-.282 0-1.08.496-2.393 1.48l-1.62-1.9 4.5-4.08c2.02-1.784 3.52-2.72 4.507-2.814 1.546-.14 2.684.314 3.41 1.367.726 1.05.996 2.415.81 4.096-.61 2.85-1.27 6.47-1.972 10.863-.046 2.01.68 3.014 2.182 3.014.655 0 1.826-.69 3.517-2.08 1.406-1.156 2.555-2.243 3.447-3.26l1.336 1.753zm-6.12-25.016c-.047 1.168-.633 2.288-1.76 3.36-1.266 1.213-2.767 1.82-4.5 1.82-2.673 0-3.964-1.165-3.87-3.498.045-1.22.76-2.39 2.144-3.51C37.89.75 39.427.19 41.117.19c.983 0 1.804.388 2.46 1.156.657.772.962 1.553.916 2.344z"/><path fill="#fff" d="M94.543 28.713c-1.314 2.484-3.117 4.733-5.416 6.748-3.145 2.72-6.285 4.08-9.426 4.08-3.05 0-4.52-1.68-4.43-5.06.05-1.5.34-3.3.88-5.41.54-2.11.83-3.75.88-4.92.05-1.78-.49-2.673-1.62-2.673-1.222 0-2.68 1.456-4.374 4.36-1.79 3.05-2.754 6.005-2.894 8.86-.095 2.02.103 3.57.59 4.648-3.27.097-5.563-.443-6.87-1.616-1.17-1.033-1.71-2.743-1.615-5.136.045-1.5.276-3 .69-4.502.414-1.5.644-2.836.69-4.01.095-1.734-.54-2.604-1.9-2.604-1.177 0-2.444 1.34-3.806 4.01-1.36 2.675-2.113 5.467-2.253 8.373-.094 2.624.074 4.453.503 5.483-3.22.096-5.506-.582-6.858-2.035-1.12-1.214-1.632-3.06-1.54-5.54.047-1.214.26-2.91.648-5.084.39-2.175.607-3.87.65-5.087.094-.843-.12-1.265-.632-1.265-.28 0-1.08.476-2.393 1.425l-1.686-1.9c.232-.184 1.71-1.545 4.43-4.08 1.97-1.826 3.304-2.764 4.01-2.81 1.216-.095 2.2.41 2.95 1.51s1.13 2.38 1.13 3.835c0 .47-.05.915-.14 1.336.7-1.077 1.52-2.017 2.46-2.814 2.155-1.875 4.57-2.93 7.244-3.167 2.3-.19 3.94.35 4.926 1.615.795 1.033 1.17 2.51 1.125 4.433.33-.28.68-.586 1.057-.915 1.08-1.265 2.135-2.27 3.166-3.02 1.737-1.268 3.54-1.97 5.42-2.113 2.25-.188 3.87.35 4.854 1.61.843 1.03 1.22 2.5 1.126 4.415-.044 1.31-.36 3.213-.946 5.712-.588 2.5-.88 3.934-.88 4.31-.048.98.048 1.66.28 2.032.236.373.797.56 1.69.56.655 0 1.825-.694 3.517-2.084 1.403-1.156 2.552-2.243 3.444-3.262l1.336 1.757z"/><path fill="#fff" d="M120.922 28.642c-1.36 2.25-4.033 4.495-8.02 6.743-4.97 2.856-10.012 4.284-15.125 4.284-3.797 0-6.52-1.27-8.16-3.8-1.172-1.74-1.734-3.8-1.688-6.19.04-3.8 1.73-7.41 5.06-10.83 3.66-3.75 7.97-5.63 12.94-5.63 4.595 0 7.032 1.87 7.313 5.61.19 2.383-1.125 4.84-3.938 7.367-3.005 2.76-6.78 4.515-11.33 5.263.843 1.17 2.11 1.753 3.8 1.753 3.375 0 7.06-.856 11.045-2.575 2.86-1.205 5.11-2.46 6.753-3.76l1.338 1.756zm-15.97-7.345c.046-1.26-.468-1.89-1.546-1.89-1.406 0-2.83.97-4.283 2.906-1.45 1.936-2.2 3.79-2.248 5.562-.025 0-.025.305 0 .91 2.295-.838 4.287-2.12 5.97-3.848 1.358-1.49 2.06-2.707 2.108-3.64z"/><path fill="#fff" d="M140.018 23.926c-.19 4.31-1.78 8.03-4.783 11.17-3.002 3.136-6.73 4.705-11.186 4.705-3.71 0-6.52-1.19-8.45-3.58-1.405-1.772-2.18-4-2.32-6.67-.237-4.03 1.216-7.73 4.36-11.1 3.38-3.74 7.62-5.62 12.732-5.62 3.28 0 5.766 1.11 7.457 3.3 1.594 2.02 2.32 4.62 2.18 7.8zm-7.95-.264c.047-1.27-.13-2.434-.527-3.49-.4-1.057-.97-1.587-1.72-1.587-2.39 0-4.36 1.293-5.9 3.877-1.316 2.115-2.02 4.37-2.11 6.766-.05 1.176.163 2.21.632 3.104.514 1.032 1.24 1.55 2.18 1.55 2.11 0 3.915-1.245 5.417-3.736 1.267-2.068 1.945-4.23 2.04-6.484z"/></svg>
        <div class="content">
                <h1>You have been temporarily blocked</h1>
                <p>Pardon the inconvenience, but our servers have detected a high number of errors from your connection. To continue, please verify that you are a human:</p>
                <form id='form' action="/_unblock_ratelimit" method="post">
                        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeRCLwSAAAAAOJ1ba_xqd3NBOlV5P_XRWJVEPdw" data-theme="light" data-callback="done"></div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="previous_url" value="">
        </form>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting the rate limit and your application is making too many requests to the Vimeo API. The rate limit ban expires after ~60 minutes after exceeding rate limit. It's best practice to immediately cease making requests to the API when a 429 error is returned, otherwise you may push back the rate limit ban reset time.

The actual rate limit varies across different account levels and endpoints, so always refer to the response headers for actual values. Here's an example of what the headers look like (obviously, your specific values will vary):

```
X-RateLimit-Limit →500
X-RateLimit-Remaining →499
X-RateLimit-Reset →2018-02-07T15:47:46+00:00
```

The best way to avoid hitting the rate limit on Vimeo's API is to use the fields filter on all your requests. Vimeo will return the lowest rate limit regardless of account type or rate limit tier if the request is unfiltered.

https://httpstatuses.com/429

https://developer.vimeo.com/guidelines/rate-limiting

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/common-formats#json-filter